# Let's Make Community Ads!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, publicity, contest

Last I heard, Community Ads were something [graduated sites could do](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1577/23788)... but recently I stumbled upon [this meta-PCG post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/lets-make-an-ad-for-our-site-and-now-vote-for-our-newly-posted-ads), so here's a shamelessly stolen meta-post :)

It's simple: you make an ad, and post it as an answer here; then the community votes for what the next ad should be.

*The highest voted ad once it has been at least two weeks, or there are at least 3 submissions with 3 votes each, or there is a submission with over 10 votes, will be posted on the community-ads post on various programming-related sites.*

Here are the rules:

- Must be 220 x 250 pixels
- Must have a border
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (i.stack.imgur.com)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

---

## UPDATE!

The marked entry has been posted on the following sites - now all we need is some more votes (score threshold is 6) :)

- [Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251196/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014/252457#252457)
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6315/community-promotion-ads-2014/6627#6627)

---

## UPDATE2!

These ads are now completing their run on the various sites. SO is now re-launching another cycle of Ads.

We cannot run two consecutive cycles on one site (against the rules), so there is no reason to be re-processing the community-ad contest.

Comment: lots of good ones here!

Comment: @Malachi I downvoted almost all of them =(. I guess we have different tastes.

Comment: there was one or two that I didn't upvote

Comment: What a run! More than 900 people clicked our ad on Stack Overflow during this round. **Can't we participate again with a new ad?** The [instructions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260377/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2014) seem to indicate that the restriction is only per *ad*, not per *project/site*. Am I wrong?

Comment: @codesparkle [it's time!](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2579/23788)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[image: python]

Comment: I like this one!

Comment: I was going to do this as a boring dictionary excerpt, but then I thought: *Heck, I could just write it in Python...*

Comment: Are those _curly_ quotes?

Comment: @200_success unless you write an OCR-based Python implementation, nobody will ever find out...

Comment: Congratulations! Your ad has been posted on Stack Overflow and Programmers - see update in question ;)

Answer (score 16):

A random idea:

[image: Code Review: The extra-strength nasal decongestant]

Just a quick and dirty sketch; the composition isn't very good at all.

But there's a "My code has no nose. / Then how does it smell? / Awful."-joke in there somewhere :P

Anyway, it'd could be fun to do something with the concept of "code smell" - the picture above unfortunately looks like an ad for a nasal decongestant :/

For some reason I'm seeing a late 1800s advertisement for "Code Review's Patented Smell Test" or something...

Answer (score 15):

As Jeff Atwood quoted in [this answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/141/23788), this site is about asking...

[image: does this code make my ass look fat?]

I think it makes a great-looking ad! :)

Comment: -1 for having the word "ass" I guess?

Comment: Maybe a missing link :)

Comment: That and I thought that Jeff's description wasn't very descriptive: if I wanted to learn what's on- and off-topic at CR (which I did) "making my ass look fat" isn't IMO a helpful answer.

Comment: "I lost 15 lines of code following this one weird tip!" :)

Comment: Jeez, I should turn all my joking comments into ads - they're getting more +1s than most of my actual ad suggestions :)

Comment: I can't help but picture "tough questions, smart answers." at the bottom!

Answer (score 15):

Maybe just a joke on "considered harmful"-code?

[image: everybody loves those old posters, right?]

Maybe someone can come up with a "better" code-smell than `goto`

Comment: try { goto codeReview; } catch (...) { betterCode(); }

Comment: @ChrisW You're saying Code Review is exceptional? :)

Comment: I hate the "Keep Calm" meme ><

Comment: @Morwenn Dude, keep calm and - oh, sorry. But yeah, I know it's a bit played out - the alt text for the image is "everybody loves those old posters, right?" :)

Comment: That's a rather personal opinion, but it has been overused. I am far from being the only being sick of seing it :/

Comment: I think this one is worth submitting again too.

Answer (score 15):

Big tip o' the hat to ChrisW who suggested something like this [in a comment on another ad](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1786/14370)

[image: Get it? ... get it?]

Get it? "Exceptional", right? Eh? Eh? *Nudge nudge* Get it?

I personally don't like the brace-on-new-line style, but 220px isn't a lot of space! :P

(edit 1: change from "good code" to "your code")
(edit 2: skipped the asterisk - see comments)

Comment: It is better pratice to [catch exceptions by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2023045/1364752).

Comment: @Morwenn Aw, man, I was afraid someone would review the "code" in the image :) Actually, I did look up proper C++ exception handling (had to; don't usually code C++), and saw that by ref was the way to go. But I chose to ignore it in the interest of graphics; `CodeReview& tips` felt less readable (in terms of ad copy). So at least it was a conscious choice on my part. But how about we pretend it's C# or something, and skip both `&` and `*` - that might be best.

Comment: I agree, we should get rid of both. It is good to have something that does not hinder readability, but having a Code Review add with non-idiomatic code in it isn't really a good idea. Let's say that it's not C++ and remove the `*`/`&` :)

Comment: I liked the word play with "pointer" ;)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Aw, I hadn't even thought of that :/

Answer (score 12):

[image: steps]

I was originally thinking of using "refactor, rethink, redesign" and other "re-" words with "review" and "refine" being the key ones. But "Review → Refine" is really the core, and this also better alludes to what's on-topic on CR (assuming "Run" actually works).

Comment: I think something like this is what we need. It's simple and it has the words *Code Review* right there. I'm not sure if I like the whole right-aligned thing though.

Comment: @jliv902 re the alignment thing: I chose it because it make "Code Review" stand out more, but also because if you read it top to bottom, you have the stages of software development. "Review" could just be a step in that list, but in this case it's not just _a_ review, but _Code Review_ the site.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. This one probably my favorite out of all of them so far.

Comment: @jliv902 Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

[image: shine]

Answer (score 6):

[image: uncle sam]

Answer (score 0):

A quick sketch/mockup:

[image]