# Let's make More Community Ads!

Tags: discussion, publicity, contest

[**Back in April**](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1781/31503) we got together and put together a shortlist of community ads that can be posted to other graduated sites. That was a very successful campaign with probably a thousand or two "click throughs" to Code Review.

Let's reboot the process and roll the ads out again!

### Results

The following are the top-3 voted candidates, and will move on to the 'post to ads' system:

- (30) [image: Mjolka]
- (27) [image: Mat's Mug]
- (22) [image: Flambino]

The possible candidate sites for these ads are (graduated, computer-related, not Stack Overflow):

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)
- [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)
- [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)
- [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/)
- [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)
- [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)

Are there graduated sites that make sense in addition to these (not Stack Overflow - off-limits)?

Last round we only targeted Programmers....

What's a good way to narrow down this decision?

I would like to see ads on Programmers, and potentially comp-sci, GameDev, and Webmasters. Possibly more. Do all the ads go to each? Decisions, decisions....

---

### What are Community Promotion Ads?

There is a [**blog post**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/) about community ads, but the short version is:

> Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will
> show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this
> question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are
> provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be
> shown.

### What are we going to do?

We are going to make ads for Code Review, and 'inject' them in to the ads that are shown on sites like [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6315/community-promotion-ads-2014)

These ads are shown in a cycle that is displayed to viewers of those sites. Any graduated site, oher than Stack Overflow, is a candidate site for community ads.

### Two Things...?

1. What sites should we advertise on?
2. What should the adverts be?

The ad submissions posted as answers on this question, that get the highest votes will be the top candidates for the actual ads on other sites. You can make special ads for certain sites if you want too. You should clearly include in your answer any details you think may be relevant.

We will run this till Halloween (Oct 31, 2014)!

### The strict rules for the ads:

- The image that you create must be 220 x 250 pixels
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

### Examples

[Look through the last round of ads that were done](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1781/31503)

The highest voted ones were:

[image: Ad1][image: Ad2]

May the odds be ever in your favor!

Comment: When we [grow up](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2545/), we'll have our own [meta-tag:community-ads] tag, and [*other sites* will come to post *their* ads](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1577/23788) on our graduated meta site!

Comment: I just like the left one. Only the comment should be changed to "Share **your working** code for peer review"

Comment: Don't have an image to go with it, but what about a play on the [Six Million Dollar Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Six_Million_Dollar_Man):  we can review your code.  make it better... stronger... faster.

Comment: Total duplicate of another question: Vote to close! Ok, kidding of course, but I have to ask: Are the non-winner ads from last time back in the running? I'm guessing no, because that feels like cheating. At the same time, this _is_ basically the same thing all over again, so ideas from last time are still relevant (full disclosure: My ads from the last round hold places 3..6, so I'm sympathetic to cheating :)

Comment: I see no problem in re-submitting previous ads, @Flambino Go for it.

Comment: 'Does this code make my ass look fat' :D

Comment: @IbrahimApachi - this has [some historical significance too](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/141/31503)... since it was essentially the 1-liner used to describe what code Review is about, when Code Review was first started.

Answer (score 32):

[image]

Theme and icons from [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/), source available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mjolka/codereview-ad). Thanks to @Mat'sMug, @IsmaelMiguel, and @200_success for suggested improvements :)

Comment: Simple, sleek, and catchy. I like it.

Comment: Nice! Only missing a little border :)

Comment: @Mat'sMug thanks, added a border :)

Comment: Nice indeed, but shouldn't we initially show the (hopefully) new user that we expect the code to be working ? How about "your working code, improved." ? As I am not a graphic person (Truth is, I hate it), I can't design such a thing.

Comment: @Heslacher I don't think it's the responsibility of the ad to educate future users, just to attract them. If CR doesn't make clear the minimum standards we have for questions (and I think we certainly fall short on that), that should be addressed in a different way.

Comment: +1 Good point .

Comment: Something tells me that those braces may be the new CR logo...

Comment: @syb0rg that gives me an idea: `{ode}eview` (has that been done?)

Comment: @mjolka an *ode* to to clean code?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel follow the [GitHub link](https://github.com/mjolka/codereview-ad).

Comment: It's not that... The window has no code. What will you be reviewing? Or is it a tiny Whitespace program?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel oh, I get you now. I thought code would clutter it up. Feel free to make a variation with code if you want :)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I've posted a version with code below.

Answer (score 28):

Jon Skeet leads the all-time SE rep score leaderboards with over 700K reputation on Stack Overflow.

[Nobody can beat Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/197901)... except on Code Review!

[image: CodeReview is graduating; come beat Jo]

---

[image: "@Mat's Mug: Fine by me." - Jon Skeet]

Comment: It might work. Personally, though, while I've heard of Jon Skeet, there was no immediate recognition. My very first impression was "Who? Oh." I actually thought it was a yearbook photo, and a play on "graduating". Then I saw the rep count, and it became "oh, so it's an SE in-joke." Though it could certainly interest those who are more tuned into the SE meta, I imagine the more casual user will stop at just "Who?"

Comment: @Flambino the "yearbook effect" is intentional. The ad is targeted at somewhat experienced SE users, aiming to attract would-be regular reviewers. Even if you don't know who Jon Skeet is, beating 551 rep shouldn't be that hard right? (and by the time you get there, you're hooked!)

Comment: Well, then I can report that the yearbook effect worked as intended :) And your points are of course valid; it would no doubt do well as an ad! I think I'm sort of an edge case: I know enough to know that I don't care, so to speak (that's too harsh a formulation, but I trust you know what I mean). I'm ok with broad memes/culture references (I mean, I did a "keep calm" poster-ad last round), but references to a sub-culture's meta discourse is a bridge too far for me :)

Comment: oh my god... I just noticed... Jon answered you _37 seconds before you'd even asked him!_ No wonder his rep is what it is! Though if I were him, I'd play the stock market

Comment: @Flambino I imagine our target market with this ad is the hundreds of thousands of people who *do* know who Jon Skeet is, since statistically they're more likely to join another SE site than a random person. #knowyourdemo

Comment: @corsiKa it's precisely because I know who he is I kinda got turned off by this. Again, personal opinion - I even said I thought it'd do well. My personal feeling is just that it's _too_ targeted. Too much of an in-joke for my taste; more about the meta of SE (rep hunting and who's who) than the _content_ and of SE and CR. That said, it'll probably be effective; it's just not my cup of tea.

Comment: I think the whole Skeet meme is horribly over-rated already. I'm not a big fan of this ad.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg TBH I'm surprised at the score this one is getting. But where's *your* ad?

Answer (score 22):

Since [the previous round's ads](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1781/31503) are allowed, I'll post my personal favorite. Incidentally, it was the least upvoted one of the 4 ads I made back then.

[image: steps]

Here's the original description:

> I was originally thinking of using "refactor, rethink, redesign" and other "re-" words with "review" and "refine" being the key ones. But "Review → Refine" is really the core, and this also better alludes to what's on-topic on CR (assuming "Run" actually works).

Comment: I really like this one. Leaving a comment because I can't vote twice...

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks, appreciated :)

Comment: In my opinion, I think you should give some space between "Code Review" and the other words. And the logo coming before the name.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Actually, the intention is present "Review" as just another verb in the list from "Design" to "Refine". It just happens to _also_ be the site's name, but here's it's mostly just another step in the process. It stands out a little more by being bolded, but not so much as to break the list of verbs completely. The logo (insofar as we have one) is just there for a bit of graphical flair, so it's not _just_ text.

Comment: @Flambino I get your idea now. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 20):

[image: simple ad]

`@throws graduation party`

Comment: nitpicking, but perhaps right-align `your code` and `great code`?

Comment: @h.j.k. outlining comments is baaad. See Clean Code on comments.

Comment: hoho must be my self-prescribed OCD kicking in then...

Comment: @h.j.k. To be honest, I spent some time in Photoshop going back and forth before deciding _not_ to align the two. But it took a while :)

Answer (score 16):

I wanted to reuse the "tough questions, smart answers" slogan from the previous round, so I combined it with [@flambino's idea](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3632/23788) and got this:

[image: word cloud; tough questions, smart answers.]

Too crowded?

Comment: +1 Nice - I was thinking of doing something similar (something à la Apple keynote slides [like this](http://www.technobuffalo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ios-8-features-slide-closeup.jpg)), but I kept coming back to "pure" text, so to speak. But this certainly works! I might skip the drop shadows, though. I think they attribute to the "crowdedness" and hurt readability somewhat

Comment: @Flambino removed the drop shadows layer.

Comment: Nice - I think it's an improvement. Simplicity and all that :)

Comment: I find the fact that the slogan has stuck hilarious. +1.

Answer (score 15):

I liked the old one that had some code in it, but it was basically demonstrating the process rather than showing some code and potential feedback on it. This might show a bit more about what you might get if you asked for a code review:

[image: You wouldn’t publish an article without copy-editing. [some code with suggestions: “use for-each”, “be consistent w/ brace pos.”, “use .equals()”, “camel-case”, “catch exceptions”, “use consistent tab size”] Why would you for code?]

The font size is a little small, but I’d have to remove something if I wanted to make it bigger. I’m no designer, so perhaps some other parts could also stand some tweaking. (Hey, maybe I could take this over to [Graphic Design.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)… hmm…) The “You wouldn’t” part was inspired by [this ad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HmZm8vNHBSU), but the general theme of that doesn’t fit; nevertheless, I think this worked out okay.

Comment: If you want to turn `Mailmessage` into `MailMessage`, I believe that's 'PascalCase'.

Comment: I like the concept, but there might be too much information in it. +1 though.

Comment: Thought the ad was the one from [IT Crowd](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xuxO6CZptck).

Comment: It's a fantastic idea, but a little cluttered. Maybe use a language without brackets (e.g. Python) to save 3 lines?

Answer (score 14):

## Best Medicine for anti-patterns : Code Review SE

Suggestions welcome

[image: Anti Pattern]

Comment: Oooh I like this one!

Comment: We could strike out Best, replace with Bad, call Bon Jovi to get his approval on putting his face on the ad, bingo! (Alright, I'm out)

Answer (score 13):

Modification suggestions are welcome

[image: First One]

New version without M$ Logo

[image: Updated]

Comment: I'd be very careful about using [a trademarked logo](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/intellectualproperty/Trademarks/EN-US.aspx) (look under "V")

Comment: @Flambino see the new version

Comment: I love it, only the Java logo (and VS logo in the first) seem like they don't fit with the others. Maybe a comment `//` instead? Otherwise great work :)

Comment: @mjolka that's coffee

Comment: Java *is* coffee ;P

Answer (score 12):

I actually deleted this one, but it seems [others have undeleted it](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2615/revisions) without my knowledge.

Personally, I just changed my mind about it. It seemed funny at first, but, if anything, it's a better joke than it is a good ad; it's crass and graphically speaking it's just not great. Hence why I deleted it to take it out of the running. But apparently I got overruled. Kinda strange, if you ask me.

If you too think it's inappropriate, by all means downvote. I'd do it myself, if I could :)

Below is the answer, unaltered from its undeleted state.

---

Ok, this is **mostly a joke** but I couldn't help myself.

[image: But we can help!]

On the pro side, it implies we're good at what we do: Cross-domain sense of smell!
On the con side, it's just low-brow and aggressive. And dumb, frankly. And it doesn't really explain anything.

I feel like it might get some clicks, though... but it'll probably lure more idly curious visitors than genuinely interested ones.

Also: Caps lock. And the typography is lackluster. Yeah, The con side is getting crowded.

Comment: While I find it funny, I don't think is the type of ads that I want to promote for Code Review.

Comment: @Marc-Andre I completely agree. As I said, I just couldn't help myself. Funny, but not the right tone.

Comment: It's cocky, but funny. I get a chuckle out of it, but loud with the caps lock. It's good to keep it around to inspire.

Answer (score 9):

[image: adjectivitis]

I admit this is pretty abstract, but that's the sort of thing I like.

I tried with "make your code..." at the start or just "... code" at the end, but either thing detracted from the visual impact, I thought.

---

Edit: Speaking of visual impact, here's a true "block" of text

```
CR makes your code
neat, maintainable
simple, extensible
concise, efficient
elegant, idiomatic
reusable, flexible
readable and clean
```

It includes the 3 extra adjectives mentioned by Simon in the comments, but it's getting a bit *too* tl;dr :)
But it's nice that you can make it line up (for no real reason) :)

Comment: Thought this was an acrostic at first.

Comment: @EngieOP Heh, nice idea actually. Too bad that this spells "scriereb" or something... Still, it is a "puzzle" in the sense that I hope the reader will figure out that all those adjectives relate to code and be intrigued. Maybe.

Comment: ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) 
+1 tho , verrry niiiccee.

Comment: You should add flexible, maintainable, extensible...

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Good ones. I had "maintainable" on there to begin with, but it just didn't look nice (too long a word). Flexible and extensible could be nice additions though. Just don't know if there's any room. I want it to stand out visually before you start reading, and the block of text and its wide margins helps that, I think. Besides, I'm not sure it's possible to do a truly exhaustive list of adjectives anyway - at least not in the space given. I'll try it out when I the time though.

Comment: `Very neat!\nNice it is\nwhen right\n` ;-)

Comment: @rolfl "Strict word arrangement / Should just make a damn haiku / But that is too trite" ;)

Comment: [I borrowed from this one a bit](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/3660/23788).

Answer (score 8):

## Yoda

suggestions welcome

[image: Yoda]

Comment: This is cool but may have some copyright infringement issues..

Comment: it's one of those pug dogs with a really big lower lip ;)

Comment: @Malachi haha yeah

Comment: "When 900 lines of code _you_ reach, smell as good, you will not!"

Comment: Also, I'm sorry, but I just couldn't help but be reminded of [this damn meme](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/c2/c2828e70e296c1c79ebda75bbde83368e9680437e62b91229ca0959ff0685936.jpg) :)

Comment: Technically, it should be "smell bad in your code is", or "smell bad your code does", or "smelly your code is", no? (better ask a native English speaker / Yoda fan for the best)

Comment: Yes, I agree the first line doesn't really sound like Yoda..

Comment: omg I hope this one will make it :D

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Created this while playing Team Fortress 2 using an online SketchPad within Steam's web browser. FYI, Jamal's team was rekt.

Also something strange happens when I use the `combine` feature on all elements. The face...WTF.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions welcome

[image: allur]

[All Your Base Are Belong To Us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us)